# Bridging, bonding and netplan

Tags: networking, network-bridge, netplan, network-bonding

I'm trying to set up a bridge over a bond for LXD using `netplan`.
This is my current configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    id0:
      match: {name: "eno[1-2]"}
      dhcp4: true
      wakeonlan: true
    switchports:
      match: {name: "eno[3-4]"}
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [switchports]
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [bond0]
      dhcp4: true
```

As you can see it's pretty straighforward.
However, after applying this configuration, the IP address assigned to `bond0` disappeared and no IP is being assigned to LXD containers (which use `br0`) or the bridge interface itself.
The issue remains on restart of the `systemd-networkd` service, the bond and bridge remain in a degraded state.
Could someone please explain what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have `dhcp4: true` set on both the bond, and the bridge which includes the bond.  You should likely only be running dhcp on the bridge.

Comment: I did notice that it didn't have any impact removing `dhcp4: true` from the bond. Why is it though? Does the bridge override the bonded interface?

Comment: If you specify to run dhcp on both the bond and the bridge, the best case is probably that you get a race condition as networkd tries to run it on both.  So you removed `dhcp4: true` from the bond, and it still doesn't work?

Comment: Correct, now `dhcp4` is explicitly `false` but `networkctl` reports the bridged interface (indefinitely) as `configuring` and `degraded`.
With a reboot things work on the server side, but a reboot of the switch or the router breaks everything once more.